# Replace static string with array results?

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I have an array (mysql datafetch return) and a static string on my html page.

```
{result}
```

I defined a function to pass variables to my html page, but in case of the array it fails:

```
$this->page = str_replace("{".$ident."}", $var, $this->page);
```

$this->page is the complete content of the html page, fetched via file_get_contents(); any ideas?

$page is just a static html page:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
{var}
```

Comment: We need more code. Post the declarations of "page" and other properties, the array, the class, "$ident", "$var" and any other thing you consider relevant.

Comment: How do you know it fails? Are you getting an error message? Is "$page" filled with garbage chars? We need more info in order to help you. Click "edit" under your question and add more info.

Comment: its just a static page (I took an edit). the array is mysql_fetch_array().

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? What is the wrong result you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you can convert the result array into a string and then replace the static variable on the HTML page. Here's how you can do this in PHP:

Convert the result array into a string, for example, using the implode() function.

Use the str_replace() function to replace the static variable on the HTML page with the string from the result array.

Here's an example code:

```
$page = file_get_contents('testCase.html');
$values = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];

$values_str = implode(", ", $values);

$ident = "var";
$page = str_replace('{' . $ident . '}', $values_str, $page);
echo $page;
```

testCase.html:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
{var}
```

Comment: Why would you prefer preg_replace in favor to str_replace in this simple case? preg_replace is an expensive operator, and it should be used very carefully, especially if you play the dangerous game of replacing content of a whole html page.

Comment: Exactly thats what I currently do. But now how to insert more than one value into the placeholder?